# Can I enable HDR on an unsupported display by force?

Tags: windows-10, display, edid, hdr

I'm currently using the latest available Windows 10 version (x64).
I have a Gigabyte GTX 750 Ti Windforce 2GB planted in my rig.

So basically what I am attempting to find on the internet, **Can I enable HDR on an unsupported display?**

I tried searching a lot and I couldn't find any answer to the question.

So that's why I'm asking it at this forum, is it possible?
Is it a simple key to change in the registry of Windows?

 Or do I have to trick Windows into thinking my display is HDR capable by changing the EDID of my display?

If I have to edit the EDID of my monitor, or some registry keys, how would I do this?

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: @NiallJones would you like to explain why such thing isn't possible? I actually don't really understand why we wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: HDR is a hardware capability. Faking it might be possible but won’t help.

Comment: @Maarten: very much simplfying it's like whether you can get coloured picture on a monochrome display with best software and graphics card

Comment: I don't think that many people understood what I'm asking about. I do _not_ expect to get HDR output on a monitor. This question was to allow to use Moonlight streaming with HDR on despite the primary monitor (directly connected) being non-HDR.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I can't figure out how to post an answer to an old question but refer to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1707661/how-can-i-turn-on-the-hdr-windows-setting-on-an-unsupported-display-by-force

I have done it personally myself, I'm using a dummy plug with HDR support and Moonlight HDR.

Answer (score 6):

In short, it's impossible to enable HDR on a non-HDR monitor. Here's why:
HDR is created by having a very high contrast ratio. For example, the contrast ratio on the iPhone Xr - which is HDR capable is around 1:1400. On your typical LCD monitor, it's around 1:600 or 1:800. 
The reason you can't enable HDR on your monitor is because the backlight can't produce enough light, and/or the liquid crystals in your display can't block out enough light to create good enough contrast. This is why HDR content looks so good on OLED displays, which can have contrast ratios of upwards of 1,000,000. The display on the iPhone 11 Pro for example, has a contrast ratio of 1:2,000,000.

Hope this helps :)

Gabe

Comment: It's a good answer to question I didn't ask :-) I don't want HDR on directly-connected monitor, I want HDR on Moonlight streaming. In fact, the PC in question doesn't have _any_ monitor connected.

Comment: This is incorrect, it is in fact possible to enable HDR on an unsupported display. I would recommend doing this on an eDID emulator/dummy plug. For more information refer to: https://superuser.com/questions/1707661/how-can-i-turn-on-the-hdr-windows-setting-on-an-unsupported-display-by-force

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to turn on HDR by the registry. But turning on a feature is all it will do if the hardware cannot provide the output and show the enhanced image.  Seen it activated, but do not know the exact settings to adjust by regedit. Will locate and edit my answer in the near future with the details. Also saw info on this subject at Howtogeek. From what I observed, a Turned on HDR did not help any on Bill's PC due to a mid range older monitor.  The card put out a good signal, and he was not using the DVI port.  The monitor simply could not handle the enhanced video signal that was produced. All the items on MS's list are really needed for a true HDR experience.  This page might help with some of the background on exactly what HDR is: https://www.datapro.net/techinfo/hdr_video_info.html I've used it for teaching a small group of High School Gamers. (Really wish people would post answers to the questions as posted, then explain why or why not..)

*New to this site, over 35 yrs in IT..see my LinkedIn profile if you wish..

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm curious to see what happens when I force HDR to a display that doesn't support it. Will it display some cool glitch, will it just play as normal, will it not be able to display any signal? Also, I want to mirror the monitor output to a HDR capable display and see if the second display can display the signal using HDR.

Comment: I don't want HDR on directly-connected monitor, I want HDR on Moonlight streaming. In fact, the PC in question doesn't have _any_ monitor connected.

Comment: I have this issue on my Surface Pro 8. It has HDR, but only enables it for Windows Store apps, and only when playing video. I'd like to enable it for games and Chrome (YouTube).

Comment: Unfortunately enabling HDR by registry does not work in Windows, you will need to flash the EDID instead. Refer to https://superuser.com/questions/1707661/how-can-i-turn-on-the-hdr-windows-setting-on-an-unsupported-display-by-force for more information.

I am not allowed to post because my reputation is low, but this is the top google result so I want to make sure people are aware it is in fact possible.