# How can I turn on the HDR Windows setting on an unsupported display by force?

Tags: windows-10, display, windows-registry, hdr

I should test a program that does different things depending on the Windows HDR setting is on or off. Altough I've a display doesn't support HDR, I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1474112/can-i-enable-hdr-on-an-unsupported-display-by-force) I can turn on the HDR by force, but I don't how do it.
I don't care if I'll see the wrong colors due to my monitor cannot handle the HDR signal, I just want see if the program I must test behaves the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You are going to need software named [CRU](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) then you are going to need to edit some options at monitor you are going to test.

Go to **Extension blocks** and double-click on **cta-861**, it will open a new window. At this window you are going to edit some things at **Data blocks**.

Go to HDMI support and enable **30-bit deep color (10bpc)** and click
“Ok.” Now go in **Colorimetry**, if you can’t find this option go to the button **Add...** and select **colorimetry**.

Now open **Colorimetry** and select **DCI-P3** and **BT.2020 RGB**, you can also enable suport for others colors standards.

And at last step here, at **Add...**, go and enable **HDR Static Metadata**, select **all 5 options**, at **luminace** you can leave empty.

Now just click “OK,” “OK” and “OK.” After all this its time to test it. In the same folder that you find `CRU.exe`, go to `restart64.exe` (here you gonna select what tipy of system you using) and double-click, this is going to force your GPU to restart the driver.

The display is going to blink and a small window is going to appear on the screen. It will show 3 options:

- **Restart again**
- **Recovery mode [F8]**
- **Exit**

If you double-click `restart64.exe`, and your display blinked but **no image appears** just press <kbd>F8</kbd> and all of the changes will reset to defalt.

Comment: This will work, but due to a bug in Windows it won't recognize the overrides done by CRU in the registry. You instead have to flash the modified EDID to the monitor using another application made by Toasty (same person who created CRU).

https://forums.blurbusters.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=9889

I would not suggest doing this on a monitor, only do that for an EDID emulator/ HDMI Dummy Adapter. Otherwise, you could potentially break your monitor, do not risk it unless you know what you're doing.

It's technically possible to "unbrick" your bricked monitor if you back it up and RDP.

Comment: Thank you. Use CRU to edit EDID, then use EDID-Writer to "flash" it to my HDMI dummy plug worked. I'm able to stream HDR games with Sunshine/Moonlight.